# Read temperature sensor from microcontroller to Android application (via microUSB)

Tags: microcontroller, usb, sensor, android

I'm working on a concept for a project, and I'm having difficulty determining whether this application is possible.

I will have some misc. microcontroller with an attached temperature sensor, and that microcontroller will be connected to an Android device via Micro USB. Is it possible to read that sensor and display results on the Android application, or are there hardware limitations to this?

Having the microcontroller send data to a server is not an option, as one of the main purposes of the project is for the Android device to handle most of the work and the microcontroller will not have network capabilities.

Comment: Temperature sensor? sounds like some kind of HID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible?  Yes -- thank you for limiting your question to the limit of my knowledge.  How do I know?  Because I've seen it, and because I [just hunted down this web page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) from Android describing how to do it.  Do I know how to do it?  Oh god no.  Could I?  Well yes, with study.  You probably can, too.

Hopefully that page will give you some Google-ish keywords that will get you to a project that uses the features you need.

Comment: I had just come across a similar page a few minutes ago, with [Host & accessory usage for USBs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb). Thanks for your reassurance, it looks like I'm on the right track.

Comment: Good.  Then, if I need to do this in a year or two I can ask here, and *you* can tell *me* how it's done!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Android supports USB HID devices, so if you [build](http:////https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/usb-hid-thermometer-software-ds18b20-attiny2313) or [buy](https://pcsensor.com/usb-thermometers/gold-temper.html) a HID thermometer the development time for the android part should be minimal.

Comment: Say I wanted to design a microcontroller that is capable of outputting power through header pins controlled by the Android device, is this considered HID as well?

Comment: it could be, it depends where the wires go. indicator lamps are.